# Sum of values excluding rows with duplicate criteria

Tags: excel

I'm certain this has a simple solution but I can't find it!

## Problem

I need to sum the values in COL B while excluding all but the first instance of the corresponding criteria in COL A, which may contain duplicate values.

#### Example Data

| Record | Count |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 1 |
| BB | 2 |
| AA | 1 |
| CC | 4 |
| DD | 7 |

Unique Record Count: 14

### Attempted Solution

I have messing with SUMIF or SUMPRODUCT but haven't been able to work out how to also include the first instance of the corresponding value for COL A. Whatever build of Excel I have doesn't have the function =UNIQUE().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Formula in D6 is:

`=SUMPRODUCT(AVERAGEIF(A2:A6;A2:A6&"";B2:B6)/COUNTIF(A2:A6;A2:A6))`

Notice this will work only if all values assigned to a Record are all the same always.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a helper column to get the summable values. E.g., in column C:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)>1,0,B2)
```

And then do a `SUM(C:C)`

#### Example Data

| Record | Count | Countable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 1 | 1 |
| BB | 2 | 2 |
| AA | 1 | 0 |
| CC | 4 | 4 |
| DD | 7 | 7 |

Comment: I always try to avoid helper columns! But hey if it works and I can hide it from getting destroyed by the vegetables I work with...

Comment: It's almost necessary given the specs. If instead of excluding all but the first, you instead require that each amount for a given value in COL A be identical, then the math is much more straightforward.